# In this context, what is a Kuhn-Tucker point?

Tags: optimization

I encountered an algorithm, and a step in the algorithm says

"Solve the NLP Problem X, to the extent of computing a Kuhn-Tucker problem."

I would like to know, is a Kuhn-Tucker point just a point that meets the KKT conditions?

If I find a local minimizer, is it a Kuhn-Tucker point?